# How to post variables to php site without access to API from local xml, csv file?

Tags: java, ajax, xml, csv, dojo

Where to find tutorial or what key words to search for to understand how to post from local *.csv, *xml file on computer to HTML/PHP site without api access.
There is only user name & password.

URL: 
https://lk.dom.mos.ru/wps/myportal/users/731/form2/!ut/p/b1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOLNPAxcPdxNjLzdQ_wsDBxdw9wD3Vx8DQ2czYEKIoEKDHAARwOwfktHSzNDYwNDL3dHL2egYKBXoJlHkKGBiQlUPx4FBOwP149CVeLv6Ao0wdHRzNvZMcDQwscYqgCPE_088nNT9QtyQyMMskwUAfcFtwM!/dl4/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/

Is it possible for user with login/password to enter data only using dojo toolkit or other applications from local xml/сым file ?

How to parse variable ID to create xml/csv with corresponding rows (fields) ?

Comment: show your research efforts; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)'s how to ask a good question.

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't ask if it was so easy to find answer. There are lots of materials how to POST on your website but very few how to parse id for variables and than create your own csv/xml with correct id to modify data in online forms